# apt-get install problem: Errors were encountered while processing: sun-j2sdk1.6

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have the following problem every time i run apt-get install:

for example : installing python-django-south

```
...
Unpacking python-django-south (from .../python-django-south_0.5-2_all.deb) ...
Setting up sun-j2sdk1.6 (1.6.0+update22-linux-i586.) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/j2sdk1.6-sun/jre/plugin/amd64/ns7/libjavaplugin_oji.so doesn't exist.
dpkg: error processing sun-j2sdk1.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up python-django-south (0.5-2) ...

Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sun-j2sdk1.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What could be the problem? 
I have 9.10 Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

As per the line:

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/j2sdk1.6-sun/jre/plugin/amd64/ns7/libjavaplugin_oji.so doesn't exist.
```

you have an invalidly set `java` path. So run from a terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and enter the number that corresponds to the correctly existing `java` path.